# PHP - How to avoid passing arguments in url

Tags: url, session, parameters, onclick

Say I have a user list and an id is associated with each row. There is an edit button associated with each row. Upon clicking the edit button, I want to display the user information. Right now I am passing the id as paramater in the url. I want to avoid that for security reasons, as not all ids should be viewed by all. I am thinking I should be able to set a session variable on the click of edit button so that when my view loads, it can get the id to load from the session.
Any idea how to set the session variable when the edit button is clicked.
Is there is better alternative?

Thanks in advance.
SK

Answer (score 0):

Passing ids in the URL is not a security concern. **Not checking whether the current user is allowed to access the given id** is a security concern. You need an *authentication* system. If somebody who's not allowed to access a specific id tries to do so, you deny the request with a `403 Forbidden` HTTP status and don't output the information.

Even with server-side state in the session (which severely breaks the idempotent nature of HTTP requests), you *still* need such a system, since you need to set the id in the session somehow and need to verify whether the user is allowed to set the session to a certain id.